# I can't write a switch to show and hide an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I want to write a switch to hide and show an element with the following code:

```
.hidden {
display:none;
}

<input type='text' id='other_elem' class='hidden' />

$('#elem').click(function(){
    if($('#other_elem').is('display'))
        $('#other_elem').hide();
    else 
        $('#other_elem').show();

});
```

I successfully show the hidden text field when I click on the button but I can't hide it when it is appear. So, can some one provide me some hints? thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.toggle()` to do that.

```
$('#elem').click(function(){
    $('#other_elem').toggle();
});
```

else, to test the visibility use `:visible` selector

```
$('#elem').click(function(){
    if($('#other_elem').is(':visible'))
        $('#other_elem').hide();
    else 
        $('#other_elem').show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. ':visible' is exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `.toggle()`

See this JS Fiddle example.
http://jsfiddle.net/sv5SV/

```
$('#elem').click(function(){
    $('#other_elem').toggle();
});
```